# How to we filter nested array in muleSoft data weave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am new for muleSoft and I have json payload like below ,I want to filter out the below json payload **characters[]** array which is having **name as 'WBB'** and **priority as '1'**

Can some one help me please.

Json Payload

---

```
{

 "status": "Success",

 "offers": [

  {

   "id": 100,

   "name": "Test1",

   "category": {

    "characters": [

     {

      "name": "WBB",

      "priority": 1

     },

     {

      "name": "ILL",

      "priority": 2

     }

    ]

   }

  },

  {

   "id": 200,

   "name": "Test2",

   "category": {

    "characters": [

     {

      "name": "WLS",

      "priority": 1

     },

     {

      "name": "DLL",

      "priority": 2

     }

    ]

   }

  },

  {

   "id": 300,

   "name": "Test3",

   "category": {

    "characters": [

     {

      "name": "INTERNET",

      "priority": 1

     },

     {

      "name": "FIBER",

      "priority": 2

     }

    ]

   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Expected payload

---

```
{
 "name": "WBB",
  "priority": 1
}
```

Comment: is it possible that there are more nesting levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`filter`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-filter) function include only selected elements from an array. This will give you an array with only elements that satisfy the filter criteria.

Now in your payload the `offers` is an array and each offer themselves have `characters` as array, so if you try `payload.offers.category.characters` you will get an array of characters (i.e. array of array) therefore you will have to [`flatten`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-flatten) it like in the below example.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(payload.offers.category.characters)
filter ((item) -> item.priority == 1 and item.name=="WBB")
```